# SAP Spartacus NullInjectorError: No provider for CmsComponentData

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I am trying to get the component data of a custom component.

```
private componentData$: Observable<CmsBannerCarouselComponent> = this.componentData.data$.pipe(
    filter(Boolean),
    tap((d: CmsBannerCarouselComponent) => (console.log("++++++++++++++++++++++++++",d)))
  );
```

I am getting the following error:

```
core.js:4197 ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[CmsComponentData 
    -> CmsComponentData -> CmsComponentData]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for CmsComponentData!
```

Can anyone help me to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the `CmsComponentData` in a constructor, it must be *provided*. This is what Spartacus is doing when a CMS component is placed on the page; while creating the component dynamically, a data object is composed and provided in the injector of that component.

The `CmsComponentData` is an abstract class, so if you add a component without injecting a concrete class, you'll face this error.

We've seen this lately by a dev who wanted to assign the component to a route. This is an example where the Angular will try to fetch a concrete class from the DI system, but there's nothing in Spartacus unless you do this yourself.

Comment: I am unable to specify the CmsComponentData in any of the providers. It is showing "Type 'type of CmsComponentData' is not assignable to type 'Provider'.".  Can you advise me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

I also faced this error. It happens when you try to add the custom component in app.component.html which is not required as these compoment are mapped through the ConfigModule. So remove the tag of the custom component from app.component.html and it will work.